# How to judge the results of the Wilcoxon test?

Tags: scipy, hypothesis-test

all! I want to conduct the Wilcoxon rank-sum test on two datasets, i.e., `x1` and `x2`. My code is as follows,

```
from scipy import stats

x1 = [9,5,8,7,10,6,7] # len(x1) = 7
x2 = [7,4,5,6,3,6,4,4] # len(x2) = 8
stats.mannwhitneyu(x1, x2)
```

Then I get the result like this,

```
> MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=6.5, pvalue=0.006966479792405637)
```

I do know how the `statistic` variable is calculated. 
But whether should I reject the null hypothesis or not according to the result generated by function `mannwhitneyu()`?

I also noticed that some other python functions return the `statistic` and `pvalue` variables. I am quite confused about the meaning of **p-value** generated by these functions, such as `ranksums()`, `wilcoxon()`, etc. Can I simply compare it with 0.05 to judge whether I should reject it or not?

Comment: Some guys told me that I only need to compare the **p-value** with **0.05**, perhaps right? In that case, p-value=0.0069<0.05, which indicates me to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: A question about the interpretation of the p-value of a statistical test should be asked over at [Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I know your means, but I just want to know how to judge whether I should reject or accept the hypothesis according to the `statistic` and `pvalue`.